# Не срабатывает dropdown

Tags: html, css, laravel

Есть код в `app.blade`-шаблоне, который `extends` в некоторых других `blade`-шаблонах.

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-sign-out"></i>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

Проблема в том, что на одном шаблоне все срабатывает, а на остальных - вижу на панели `Network` срабатываение `/favicon.ico` по нажатию на `<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" ...>`.
Пробовал удалить сам файл `favicon` - не помогло. `css` на вышеуказанных страницах подключены одинаковые.

Comment: js boostrap подключен на странице, где не срабатывает открытие менюшки?

Comment: @tcpack4 спасибо, проблема была в этом